# Postgres all_source table equivalent

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

In Oracle SQL I have often used ALL_SURCE table like:

```
select * from all_source where upper(text) like upper('%some_code_line%');
```

Is there any equivalent of this select statement in Postgres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function's (or procedure's) source is stored in [`pg_proc.prosrc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-proc.html), so the following would be similar:

```
select proname
from pg_proc
where upper(prosrc) like upper('%some_code_line%');
```

If you want, you can restrict it to only functions and procedures using `and prokind in ('f', 'p')`

Answer (score 1):

You will get all functions details in postgresql using below query,

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.routines;
```

If you are expecting all the packages, in postgresql you have multiple tables listed in the below link, please make use of it

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html

Comment: `all_source` stores the PL/SQL code for procedures and functions in Oracle. It has nothing to do with tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for clarifying. Provided the table name when we can find all the functions

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create view which is very similar to all_source from Oracle:

```
create or replace view all_source as 
select 
proowner::regrole as owner,
proname AS name, 
regexp_split_to_table(prosrc, E'\\n+') as text
from pg_proc
order by name;
```

Then I'll just have to do this:

```
select * from all_source
where upper(text) like upper('%some_code_line%');
```